# How to add buttons in ionic FCM push notification

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I would like to send a push notification with 2 buttons as in the picture.
[image]

I am receiving the notification, but it does not have the buttons.
here is the code of the notification:

```
let notification = {
  "notification": {
    "title": title,
    "body": msg,
    "sound": "default",
    "click_action": "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
  }, 
  "actions": [
      {
        "title": "Subscribe",
        "action": "subscribe",
      },
      {
        "title": "Unsubscribe",
        "action": "unsubscribe"
      }
    ]
  ,
    "android":{
    "ttl":"2419200s"
  },
  "to":'/topics/'+topic,
  "priority": "high"
};
```

please how to solve this

Comment: if u need more customable notfication service, use onesignal... it have plugin and good documentation within onesignal site and much customizations can be done with it (buttons, images, grouping messages, etc.. `Check the onesignal docs if interested`)

Comment: Have you seen this plugin - https://github.com/havesource/cordova-plugin-push ?

Comment: @AkshayaJeevan Checked, not working even if I followed strictly with the doc. Button is still not showing somehow.

Comment: I think your "actions" field should be inside of the notification field, though.